# can we call method M1 for abstract class A?

Tags: c#

experts,

below is code for abstract class with virtual method and override in class B.

Can we call method M1 of class A, as we can't instantiate this? thanks,

```
public abstract class A
{
    public virtual int M1(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override int M1(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: ok, just for a reason we can't instantiate? thanks!

Comment: public class C : A { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as `B` overrides `M1` virtual method dispatch will make `B.M1()` being called, even when you cast instance of `B` to `A`.

The only place you can call it is from within `B` code, using `base.M1()` syntax:

```
public override int M1(int a, int b)
{
    var temp = base.M1(a, b);
    return temp - a - b;
}
```

However, there can be another class inheriting from `A` (lets name it `C`), which does not override `M1`. In that case, calling `M1` on instance of `C` will invoke `A.M1()`.

Comment: can you not also refer to `base.M1()` elsewhere in B?

Answer (score 0):

You must instantiate a class that implements A1, virtual is a method you CAN override but if you don't it will execute the base class method.